# Why does my menu jump when I click on a diffrent link in the navigation?

Tags: css, menu

The menu jump form the left to the right and then back again when I go through the navigation. If I'm in link 1 and click link two, the navigation (not the page) jumps and when I click link 3, same thing.

I can't fiddle it or post the code because it's 4 pages.

Why does it do that and how do I fix it?

EDIT:

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul> 
        <li><a href="../index.html">> om oss</a></li>
        <li><a href="vad.html">> vad vi gör</a></li>
        <li><a href="retorik.html">> vad är retorik?</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="teknik.html">Presentationsteknik</a></li>
                <li><a href="page/retotikkrea.html">Retorik & kreativitet</a></li>
                <li><a href="chefledare.html">Chef eller ledare?</a></li>
                <li><a href="grunder.html">Retorikens grunder</a></li>
                <li><a href="memoria.html">Memoria</a></li>
                <li><a href="foretagsretorik.html">Företagsretorik</a></li>
                <li><a href="hallatal.html">Hålla tal</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="sidor/weekend.html">> storytelling</a></li>
        <li><a href="sidor/fq.html">> kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav {
    background-color: #8D8084;
}

#nav ul {
    margin:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 12px;
}

#nav li {
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
}

#nav ul ul li
{
 display:block;
}


#nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
    padding-right: 60px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin: -12px;
    background:#8D8084;
    font-family: Candara,"Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

#nav ul ul li a
{    
    width:170px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#nav ul li.active  a {
    background-color:#A4999D;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color:#A4999D;
    color:#FFF;
}

#nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:18px;
    left:-24px;
}

#nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: We are unable to help you as long as you dont provide any code.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to find a way to condense your code, and provide a link or paste the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your parent div doesn't have a fixed width and height:

```
#nav {
    background-color: #8D8084;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing changed. Still the same problem.

Comment: @SabaaAlkatib could you make a JSFiddle from the code, where the issue is the same?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sabaalk/ch4kffty/6/ Dont know how much it will help, you cant see the jump if you dont change the page.

Comment: @SabaaAlkatib I cant seem to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thats because you need to click and come to a diffrent page in the navigation. It doesnt jump if you click on the same link you are in.

Comment: @SabaaAlkatib what happens if you add a float:left;

Comment: the navigation gets messed up and the problem is the same

Comment: @SabaaAlkatib Sorry I don't think I can fix the issue.